# Query Of Queries runtime error: Table name was not found in memory

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I am getting a coldfusion error on referencing query from application variable.

Application.Shops is an application variable and is a query referenced in another file.

```
<cfquery name="qFilterLocations" dbtype="query">
    SELECT * FROM Application.Shops
</cfquery>
```

However, I do get 'Error Executing Database Query. Query Of Queries runtime error.Table named Application.Shops was not found in memory. The name is misspelled or the table is not defined.

I don't understand what is wrong here.

Comment: Try using associative array notation - `Application['Shops']`

Comment: I have used this in so many files before, but it never threw an error, however they have been referenced as  <cfset qShops = Application.Shops>

Comment: Can you dump it?

Comment: yes, its being referenced at so many places so am not sure why this wouldn't work, except this is a query of a query

Comment: Have you tried `[Application].Shops`  as table name?

Comment: My guess is that CF is applying the dot notation in a different way. The dots in a table name mean something else and therefore Application.Shops is not getting parsed as expected. And that's why `<cfset qShops = Application.Shops>` works. See https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/accessing-and-using-data/using-query-of-queries/query-of-queries-user-guide.html

Comment: oh ok, so what do you suggest instead of dot notation?

Comment: The query works without issue in  2016,0,17,325979 .

Comment: It works fine with  2016,0,01,298513 too. Sounds like the issue is something else ... Could you verify your CF version? `#server.coldFusion#`

Comment: we are using CF 2018

Comment: The question tags say CF2016, but it works with CF 2018 too, as long as the query actually exists in the app scope. Dump the app scope. Is the query there?

Comment: It does, I think this one is just bit odd, am going to use what snackboy has below and just go with it for now, thanks all for the help!

Comment: Yeah, I think it's something specific to your app setup, as QoQ's have no problem with that syntax otherwise. Anyway, glad you found a workaround for the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that CF is interpreting the dot notation in a specific way (see https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/accessing-and-using-data/using-query-of-queries/query-of-queries-user-guide.html). I would restructure the code in the following way:

```
<cfset qShops = Application.Shops>
<cfquery name="qFilterLocations" dbtype="query">
    SELECT * FROM qShops
</cfquery>
```

Follow Up: I was able to run the following in CF2018 with no issue. As @SOS suggested, this is likely a specific environment issue.

```
<cfquery datasource="myDS" name="application.shops">
    select 1 from dual
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#application.shops#">

<cfquery dbtype="query" name="qResult">
    select * from application.shops
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#qResult#">
```

Both query results are dumped without error.

Comment: FWIW, this is probably a special environment specific case, as CF2016 and CF2018 have no problem referencing Application.Shops in a QoQ  :)

Comment: @SOS, I think you are right. I updated my answer with test code validating that the dot notation works in at least CF18 without error.